# How to install symbolic package in Octave for ubuntu?

Tags: octave

> pkg install -forge symbolic
>   error: could not download file symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz from url http://packages.octave.org/download/symbolic-2.6.0.tar.gz

error: called from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just hit the same problem. The solution is to check if you have pip

```
sudo apt-cache policy python-pip
```

which should return either:

```
  python-pip:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.5.4-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1.5.4-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

meaning it isn't installed. Or:

```
python-pip:
  Installed: 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 1.5.4-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.4-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5.4-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

if it is installed. If not installed run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Now you can run pip to get the new sympy

```
pip install --user sympy
```

Finally back to octave to run

```
pkg install -forge symbolic
```

or

```
pkg install /PATH/YOU/DOWNLOADED/TO/symbolic-2.2.4.tar.gz
```

if you downloaded the tar of the version you need.

Last and final step: Each time your run octave, you need to load the symbolic package,

```
pkg load symbolic
```

or you can put this command in your `~/.octaverc`.

Comment: It's better to add `pkg load symbolic` to scripts which needs the functionality rather than adding it globally

Comment: Thank you sir. I have another query, how to use 'symp' in octave-symbolic-2.6.0